# Update a bootstrapper application using msi package without duplicates in ARP window

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

Is it possible to upgrade an application installed through a Wix burn bootstrapper installer using the updated .msi, without getting duplicates in the "Add remove programs" window?

My scenario:
I have two msi packages bundled with some dependencies in a bootstrapper application. Lets call them "application" and "templates"

I would like to send an update of only the templates without having to include everything else in the update.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the "Add remove programs" window is to allow the user to uninstall programs. Bundles will only uninstall MSIs that it has installed. So if you install a bundle and then manually upgrade one the MSIs that was installed by that bundle, then uninstalling the bundle will not uninstall that upgraded MSI. The behavior here is correct because it is allowing the user to uninstall everything that was installed.

Related bundles were added for these kinds of scenarios but their behavior was not documented so I can't recommend how to solve this problem with them.

The other option is to provide a newer bundle that includes the updated package along with the original versions of all the other packages. If you can make the packages available for download then the size of the bundle will still be small.